# Listing documents directory contents in UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, directory, tableview

So I've researched extensively on how to list the files in the documents directory in a table view and after much deliberation, came up with this code. Whenever I run this, the app crashes with EXEC_BAD_ACCESS.
I've been busting my head for hours, so any help would be appreciated.

All I'm doing is acquiring the files in the documents directory and trying to list them in a table view...

Code is pasted in link below.

http://pastie.org/4178767

Edit-
App crashes in numberOfRowsInSection: method.

Comment: Your question would be more useful if you could specify ***where*** in your code does your app crash?  is there a backtrace?  or can you step through with the Xcode debugger to isolate where the crash is happening?

Comment: Sorry about that, it crashes in the numberOfRowsInSection: method. Which is strange, because when I log the count in the array it returns a number (so it should work properly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using ARC (Automated Reference Counting)? If not you should `retain` the value returned from `contentsOfDirectoryAtPath`.

```
directoryContent = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:NULL] retain];
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much Hejazi! I feel stupid not catching that.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be something wrong here:

```
cell.textLabel.text=@"File %d: %@", [directoryContent objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Change to:

```
cell.textLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"File %d: %@", [directoryContent objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

Also, you aren't attaching anything to match the %d format specifier.